# Android Studio won't recognize fonts nor images on drawable

Tags: android-studio

I'm having two problems questions regarding Android Studio.
Take note that it is only one Project I started to learning using "Empty View Activity"

First one:

1. I wanted some custom fonts. So I right-clicked on my res folder, then New>Android Resource Directory and created a folder named font, the type o resource being font too. I added my fonts, as you can see in the image below. Than, I went to my activity_main.xml, typed "android:fontFamily=@" and it didn't show any font at all. Even if type the name of the font by myself, it will not recognize
2. I also tried adding and image to the drawable folder, but when I tried to create and ImageView with that image, the image was not there, I had to import it by clicking on the plus icon, to add images to the module, selectin "Import Drawables" and choosing the path of the image. Is trhis supposed to be like that?

[Print of fonts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W329J.png)